# How can I make Fragments dynamically using input from user (User Input = Number of Fragments)

Tags: android, tabs, android-viewpager, fragment

I am very new to Android specifically to Fragments. I am making a Tab layout using ViewPager and Fragments.

Now my problem is that, I want to add fragment to viewpager dynamically meaning The number of tabs will be according to users input. If user selects 10 then 10 Fragments should be created at Runtime/Dynamically. I don't want to pre-define the fragments.

I have looked at lot off solution but none of them was any helpful.

I will really appreciate some kind of guidance.

**Thanks**